# Weird behaviour of =~ in bash

Tags: bash, regex, bash-scripting

So, I am doing this:

```
[[ 'Comment 1: abcas'  =~ '(?:Comment [0-9]*: )(.*)' ]]
```

The regex works fine with many online regex testers and in js, but failed to work in bash. Anyway modification to my regex to extract `abcas` from the

> 'Comment 1: abcas'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b):

> An additional binary operator, ‘=~’, is available, with the same
>   precedence as ‘==’ and ‘!=’. When it is used, the string to the right
>   of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and
>   matched accordingly (**as in regex3**)). The return value is 0 if the
>   string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise. If the regular expression
>   is syntactically incorrect, the conditional expression’s return value
>   is 2. If the nocasematch shell option (see the description of shopt in
>   The Shopt Builtin) is enabled, the match is performed without regard
>   to the case of alphabetic characters. **Any part of the pattern may be
>   quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string.**

So, your quotes around the regex cause the entire regex to be treated as a plain string match. Also, there are many flavors of regex out there, and `?:` is not supported by [`regex(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regex) -- you just have to check the manual to see what flavor any particular tool supports, unfortunately.

In your specific case, you can use something like

```
$ [[ 'Comment 1: abcas' =~ (Comment [0-9]*: )(.*) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
abcas
```

Comment: Yup. That's right. Thanks. I was thinking about *regex3* as well! But, couldn't find any useful reference for it. Could you provide one if you have?

Comment: [`regex(7)`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/regex) and [POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) may be helpful. `regex(3)` is linked in my answer.

Comment: POSIX.1 is the one that I am looking for! :)